# Which library should I use for server-side image manipulation on Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, image-processing, image-manipulation

I found a quite [large list of available libraries](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-graphics) on Node.JS wiki but I'm not sure which of those are more mature and provide better performance. Basically I want to do the following:

1. load some images to a server from external sources
2. put them onto one big canvas
3. crop and mask them a bit
4. apply a filter or two
5. Resize the final image and give a link to it

Big plus if the node package works on both Linux *and Windows*.

Comment: Question already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541332/whats-the-best-graphics-library-for-node-js-for-image-cropping

Comment: 2015: this also seems legit: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp

Comment: @jm_____ stackoverflow is both a Q&A and a wiki. feel fre to edit the answer so that more people notice it.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

*Answering my own question*

I spent two days digging through Node.js graphics libraries.

[**node-canvas**](https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas)

- I tried it first since I'm quite familiar with `<canvas>` API. It's a huge plus for a library.
- it requires Cairo which doesn't have an easy Windows download. I found it in GTK+ distribution though.
- moreover it needs native library binding code to be compiled on module installation. It uses Node-Waf which hasn't being ported to Windows yet.

[**gm**](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm)

- mature
- runs on Windows smoothly
- docs are *ok* but not thorough: I had to look up into source code to figure out what API is available
- unfortunately there's no easy way to combine images with gm. Maybe there's some way to achieve that but I haven't found one after two hours spent with it.

[**node-imagemagick**](https://github.com/yourdeveloper/node-imagemagick)

- The official repo has very few basic ImageMagick commands covered but I used [this fork](https://github.com/msealand/node-imagemagick) (good thing that NPM can pull libraries directly from git repositories). It has bindings for `montage` which does exactly what I need.
- [ImageMagick is quite slow](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/benchmarks.html#the-benchmark), though it works on Windows.

[**Node-Vips**](https://github.com/dosx/node-vips)

- Huge plus: it uses an incredible [VIPS library](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/) which I'm familiar with. VIPS is very fast and optimized for large images. It's very smart about utilizing hardware resources: if your machine has a lot of RAM it'll do all processing in memory but will switch to hard-drive caches if memory is scarce or required for other applications.
- same as node-canvas it requires Node-Waf so it's not available for Windows yet.

I also looked at other libraries from the list but most of them are either very immature or do not suit my use case. I would really like to try migrating to either Node-Canvas or Node-Vips when Node-Waf gets ported to Windows but until then I'll stick to node-imagemagick.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to answer your own question. Great write up!

Comment: On Windows gm seemed a bit slow for me - though I think this is partly down to how long it took to spawn instances of the gm executable.

Comment: Node-waf has been replaced by node-gyp in the meantime, so installation of node-canvas should be possible on Windows according to https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows

Comment: I haven't confirmed this by testing but it looks like gm does support montage: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/75

Comment: Time changed and NODE-Vips had 1yr+ no update. I recommend to add **Sharp** to the list instead. It uses also VIPS and is activly maintained: https://github.com/lovell/sharp

Comment: For those stepping into this question these days, [LWIP](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip) is another good alternative. No external dependencies, it relies on a node.js C++ addon.

Comment: Is there a library like LWIP which doesn't have external dependencies but with the feature to draw text over image? @MaxArt

Comment: https://github.com/lovell/sharp , another node binding for libvips, now works on Windows.

Comment: I think you can montage now https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#montage

Comment: Found Jimp : https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp looks great on paper, haven't tried it yet.

Comment: [jsdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom) can give you access to the HTML canvas, from there you should be able to manipulate images on the canvas. [How to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom#canvas-support)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn jsdom uses node-canvas to achieve this so there is no advantage in using jsdom when you can use node-canvas directly instead.

Answer (score 6):

I'd strongly advise you to check [gm](http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/) with GraphicsMagick.
Stable, feature rich, clean API, great docs, and fast.

And it works both on Windows and Linux / MacOS / BSD / ...

Answer (score 3):

Her is the [link](https://bitbucket.org/pastorgluk/node-canvas-win) to canvas implementation based on GDI+

Comment: I can't get this thing to run at all. I just get "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" as soon as I require it.