# azure mobile service - Hosting Images

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I've been using the Azure Mobile Service for the last 4 months and I'm very happy with the results.I can create and maintain a backend service with no issues.

The only thing I did not find how to implement is Image Manipulation and Hosting.

My iOS app needs to upload files to the server and the server will resize/crop the images to generate some thumbnails.

Right now Im hosting the images in Amazon s3 and the resizing is done in the client. The problem with is that I need to upload 2 images instead of just one.

What are the options to solve my situation using only the Azure Mobile Services?

Answer (score 4):

For storing images, you could possibly use Azure Blob Storage instead of Amazon S3. One benefit you would get out of it is lower latency between your mobile service and storage.

Coming to your 2nd question, you would need some kind of server side processing to work with the images once they're received at the mobile service end. I've not worked extensively with node.js, but a quick search led me to this thread on SO: [Which library should I use for server-side image manipulation on Node.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692075/which-library-should-i-use-for-server-side-image-manipulation-on-node-js). You could possibly use one of the libraries mentioned there to process the image in mobile service itself and then push both images into storage.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will take a look in the Azure Blob Storage solution.