# finding the coordinates (x,y) of numbers in an image

Tags: node.js, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I have an Image with numbers scattered all over the image. The numbers are in a very clear font and resolution. It means that image quality will probably wont be an issue. The image format can also be flexible.

I need to identify the numbers and get the coordinates of each number in the image.

Later i will take a Numbers-Free copy of the image and write some text at the given coordinates.(That part is already written)

I couldn't find anything that is able to do that over the web.

My server is Ubuntu and i prefer to use NodeJS but has no problem using something else if it will get the job done.

here is an example image i need to work on, all i need is to get the numbers and their coordinates from the image:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have just one image to process? If more than one, please give a second sample if different.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The images are of the same kind but not identical. they will have the same colors and the numbers will look the same, but the position of the numbers will be different and can be all over the image.
(Its a floor plan)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692075/which-library-should-i-use-for-server-side-image-manipulation-on-node-js) you can find some image-processing libraries for Node.JS.

But without a sample image it is hard to say what you should do! Do you just wan't the location or the exact number? Whats your background color and does it differ? ...

I found a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413216/simple-digit-recognition-ocr-in-opencv-python) that might help with recognizing the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help if you could post your image (or a link to the image).

With Python's scikit-image, a possible strategy would be

- to segment the pixels corresponding to the numbers, for example by thresholding the image and detecting connected components (see http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_thresholding.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-thresholding-py for thresholding
  and http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-label-py for labeling connected components)
- and for the coordinates of the numbers, you can either extract the coordinates of the bounding box (like in http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-label-py or http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-regionprops-py), or retrieve all coordinates of the pixels with `skimage.measure.regionprops`.